# MySQL Query giving error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the flights no whose seats are more 0. I have 3 table in MySQL

```
1. Sector
2. Flights
3. Aircraft
```

please see the image for structure of table in sequence of 1,2 and 3
[image]

I am writting this SQL

```
select * from aircraft 
where aircrafttypeID=
       (select aircrafttypeID 
            from sector,flights 
             where source like 'Kolkata' 
             and destination like 'Ahmedabad' 
             and sector.sectorID=flights.sectorID) 
and bseats>0
```

This query is giving error -

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

because subquery is retuning multiple flight numbers. So I need some help how can get those Flights Number whose seats are more than 0

Comment: Try replacing `=` with `in` ...

Comment: @MeherzadThanks I forgot IN yes its done

Comment: @Pheonix answer is a better fix for you in my view. The join is better and cleaner than the subquery to use in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a suggestion. You can use join instead on subquery.

```
select * 
from aircraft a 
inner join flights f
on a.aircrafttypeID=f.aircrafttypeID
inner join source s 
on s.sectorID=f.sectorID
and s.source LIKE 'Kolkata'
and s.destination LIKE 'Ahmedabad'
and a.bseats>0
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    aircraft
WHERE   aircrafttypeID IN ( SELECT   aircrafttypeID
                            FROM     sector ,
                                     flights
                            WHERE    source LIKE 'Kolkata'
                                     AND destination LIKE 'Ahmedabad'
                                     AND sector.sectorID = flights.sectorID
                     )
    AND bseats > 0
```